# Sinatra/Ruby default a parameter

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there a way to default a parameter in Sinatra?

I am currently looking to see if `'start'` was passed as a parameter, but it seems a little hacky.  It would be nice if I could tell Sinatra to default certain parameters if they are not specified.

```
get '/comments/?' do
   # want to setup page stuff, default to first page if not specified
   params[:start] = 0 if !params[:start] 
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd use `||=` unless you're setting booleans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that you can use `||=` in this way, but it's a very strange thing to set the params *after* retrieving them. It's more likely you'll be setting variables *from* the params. So instead of this:

```
params[:start] ||= 0
```

surely you're more likely to be doing this:

```
start = params[:start] || 0
```

and if you're going to do that then I'd suggest using [fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)

```
start = params.fetch :start, 0
```

If you're *really* looking for default values in the parameters hash before a route, then use a [before filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters)

```
before "/comments/?" do
  params[:start] ||= 0
end
```

---

#### Update:

If you're taking a parameter **from the route pattern** then you can give it a default argument by using block parameters, because Ruby (from v1.9) can take default parameters for blocks, e.g.

```
get "/comments/:start/?" do |start=0|
  # rest of code here
end
```

The `start` parameter will be available via the `start` local variable (given to the block) or via `params[:captures].first` (see [the docs for more on routes](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes)).

---

#### Further update:

When you pass a route to a verb method (e.g. `get`) the Sinatra will use that route to match incoming requests against. Requests that match fire the block given, so a simple way to make clear that you want some defaults would be:

```
get "/comments/?" do
  defaults = {start: 10, finish: 20}
  params = defaults.merge params
  # more code follows…
end
```

If you want it to look cleaner, use a helper:

```
helpers do
  def set_defaults( defaults={} )
    warn "Entering set_defaults"
    # stringify_keys!
    h = defaults.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
      h[k.to_s] = defaults[k]
    end
    params.merge!( h.merge params )
  end
end

get "/comments/?" do
  set_defaults start: 10, finish: 20
  # more code follows…
end
```

If you need something more heavyweight, try [sinatra-param](https://github.com/mattt/sinatra-param).

---

#### Sinatra::DefaultParameters gem

I liked this bit of code so much [I've turned it into a gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-default_parameters).

Comment: 'but it's a very strange thing to set the params after retrieving them', agreed, that is why I called it a little 'hacky'.  I am not sure a before filter is much better.  I was really hoping for something like get '/comments[:start = 0]/?' or something similar.  Seems pretty common to be able to do that with Routing frameworks.

Comment: Thanks iain, looks like the thought about 'path' parameter defaults but not url parameter defaults, i.e. /comments?status.  Looks like there is no perfect answer at this point.

Comment: @forumuser Personally, I think that syntax is ugly, but there is a syntax out there for everyone :) Either way, `'/comments[:start = 0]/?'` [would be an invalid url due to the slash at the end](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-23). Wouldn't `'/comments/?[:start = 0]'` be closer to valid? (and even then, square brackets are valid parts of a querystring, so the whole idea of using them as syntax elements seems daft!)

Comment: agreed that the syntax is not optimal, was just an example/idea.  Most restful languages/impls have the idea of defaulting both path and query parameters. Seems like Sinatra can only default path parameters at this point, not query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "or equals" operator here: `params[:start] ||= 0`

http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: Sure that is a Ruby shortcut, but has nothing to do with Sinatra detecting that a parameter was not passed on the url and defaulting it.