# Several optional parameters in sinatra route

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I need the Sinatra route to behave in the following manner:

```
GET /list/20/10  # Get 20 items with offset 10
GET /list/20     # Get 20 items with default offset
GET /list        # Get default number of items with default offset
```

I understand, I might pass the values as query:

```
GET /list?limit=20&offset=10
```

but I want to pass them as described above. I am pretty sure there is a way to explain to Sinatra/Padrino what I want to do, but I’m currently totally stuck with. I have tried:

```
get :list, :map => '/list', :with => [:limit, :offset] {} # 404 on /list
get :list, :map => '/list/*' { puts params[:splat] } # 404 on /list
get :list, :map => '/list/?:limit?/?:offset?' {} # 404 on /list
get :list, :map => '/list' { redirect url_for(:list, …) } # 302, not convenient for consumers
```

How am I supposed to notice Sinatra that the parameter might be optional?

Accidentally,

```
get %r{/list(/[^/]+)*} do
  # parse params[:captures]
end
```

works, but that looks silly.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14885171/1120015

Comment: @UriAgassi That’s the same as grepping `regex`, I look for more clear ans straight way.

Comment: I thought that the `get "/comments/:start/?" do |start=0|` does the trick for you...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sinatra'

get '/test/?:p1?/?:p2?' do
  "Hello #{params[:p1]}, #{params[:p2]}"
end
```

just works for `/test`, `/test/a` and `/test/a/b`. Did I miss something in your question?

Comment: Ooups… Now it works for me like a charm. Looks like the error was induced. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So you need two ? to surround each optional named parameter?

Comment: Yes, the documentation is very scarce with regards to optional parameters but that's how they are defined. Using a question mark was maybe an awkward decision as it can lead to confusion with the one used for the query string.

Comment: Optional parameters don't need two question marks. A question mark shows that the preceding character or parameter is optional. In this case it shows that the slash is optional, and that the parameter is optional.

Comment: @Jrgns you are absolutely right, the documentation could really do with an explanation of what is the exact effect of the question mark, I'll submit a bug report later on

Answer (score 4):

Actually the parameters matching in Sinatra is done by [Mustermann](http://www.sinatrarb.com/mustermann/) and according to the documentation you have several matchers available.

In the sinatra you have:

```
sinatra     /:slug(.:ext)?
```

So if you want optional parameters you need to wrap them in `()?` like the example above, taken from the documentation.